# How to store JDBC locally to run pyspark in EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run some code locally to AWS, but I'm not sure where to store the jdbc drivers. The goal is to have my pyspark application, read a rds database to do an ELT process from a cluster.

I'm getting two sets of errors:
First: `Cannot locate jar files`
Two: `Error: Missing Additional resource`

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--driver-class-path /path/to/driver/jars --jars /file/path/to/jars' 

post_df = spark.read\
    .format("djbc") \ 
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgres:url-to-rds-amazonaws.com") \
    .option("dbtable", "mytable") \ 
    .option("user", "myuser") \ 
    .option("password", 'passowrd') \
    .query("select * from my table").load()

post_df.createOrReplaceTempView("post_fin_v")

transformed_df = spark.sql('''
perform more aggregation here


''')
transformed_df.write.format("jdbc").mode("append").option("url", "jdbc:sql_server:url-to-rds-amazonaws.com") \
    .option("dbtable", "mytable") \ 
    .option("user", "myuser") \ 
    .option("password", 'passowrd')
```

Comment: Drop it into S3 bucket, copy from there to EMR cluster in init/pre-script/step

Comment: @Bala I'm not sure I understand.